# Can sqlite-utils convert function select two columns?

Tags: sqlite, datasette

I'm using sqlite-utils to load a csv into sqlite which will later be served via Datasette. I have two columns, `likes` and `dislikes`. I would like to have a third column, `quality-score`, by adding likes and dislikes together then dividing likes by the total.

The [sqlite-utils convert](https://sqlite-utils.datasette.io/en/stable/cli.html#converting-data-in-columns) function should be my best bet, but all I see in the documentation is how to select a single column for conversion.

`sqlite-utils convert content.db articles headline 'value.upper()'`

From the example given, it looks like `convert` is followed by the db filename, the table name, then the col you want to operate on. Is it possible to simply add another col name or is there a flag for selecting more than one column to operate on? I would be really surprised if this wasn't possible, I just can't find any documentation to support it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect answer as it doesn't resolve whether sqlite-utils supports multiple column selection for transforms, but this is how I solved this particular problem.

Since my `quality_score` column would just be basic math, I was able to make use of sqlite's [Generated Columns](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/gencol.html). I created a file called `quality_score.sql` that contained:

```
ALTER TABLE testtable
ADD COLUMN quality_score GENERATED ALWAYS AS (likes /(likes + dislikes));
```

and then implemented it by:

`$ sqlite3 mydb.db < quality_score.sql`

You do need to make sure you are using a compatible version of sqlite, as this only works with version 3.31 or later.
Another consideration is to make sure you are performing math on integers or floats and not text.

Also attempted to create the table with the virtual generated column first then fill it with my data later, but that didn't work in my case - it threw an error that said the number of items provided didn't match the number of columns available. So I just stuck with the ALTER operation after the fact.